# Convert Json DateTime to C# DateTime

Tags: json, json.net

I'm consuming a REST service that is returning date's in the following format:

```
{
   "uploadedOn" : "\/Date(1416421811000-0800)\/"
}
```

Trying to figure out how i can convert this to c# DateTime. Tested a few off the wall ideas that got close but no dice.  I thought possibly the -0800 was the GMT offset and parsing the value excluding that but that did not work.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any indication of what date the value in parens corresponds to?

Comment: Yep. This is the value returned by the same service as xml which is easily parsed. 2014-11-19T10:30:11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're getting back looks like a Java timestamp with an offset of -8 hours, which will require some work to parse (unfortunately none of the native parsing methods will work out of the box).

Something like this (adjust as needed) should work for you:

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {   
        var offsetParsedDate = GetDateTimeOffset("1416421811000-0800");

        Console.WriteLine(offsetParsedDate);

    }

    static DateTimeOffset GetDateTimeOffset(string inDate)
    {
        string delimiter = "-";

        if(inDate.IndexOf("+") != -1)
        {
            delimiter = "+";
        }

        string[] dateParts = inDate.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, 2, System.StringSplitOptions.None);

        DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

        var parsedDate = epoch.AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(dateParts[0]));

        var offset = TimeSpan.ParseExact(dateParts[1], "hhmm", null, delimiter == "-" ? System.Globalization.TimeSpanStyles.AssumeNegative : System.Globalization.TimeSpanStyles.None);

        return new DateTimeOffset(parsedDate, offset);      
    }
}
```